# Alignment issues with \varprojlim and \varinjlim

Tags: tikz-pgf, amsmath, tikz-arrows, math-operators

I want to replace the default arrows in my document with the `tikz` `angle 45` arrows. However, the glyphs do not fit well with the macros `\varprojlim` and `\varinjlim`. The horizontal alignment of the arrows is a bit off and the horizontal spacing between the limit symbols seems to be larger than before. How can I center the arrows correctly and remove the extra spaces around the symbols?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}

\renewcommand{\rightarrow}{\vcenter{\hbox{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=angle 45] \draw[->] (0, 0) -- (10pt, 0); \end{tikzpicture}
}}}

\renewcommand{\leftarrow}{\vcenter{\hbox{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=angle 45] \draw[<-] (0, 0) -- (10pt, 0); \end{tikzpicture}
}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\textstyle\varprojlim_{A \subseteq B} \quad \textstyle\varinjlim_{A \subseteq B}
\]

\end{document}
```

Original definitions of `\varprojlim` and `\varinjlim`.

```
\def\varlim@#1#2{\mathop{\vtop{\ialign{##\crcr
 \hfil$#1\m@th\operator@font lim$\hfil\crcr
 \noalign{\nointerlineskip}#2#1\crcr
 \noalign{\nointerlineskip\kern-\ex@}\crcr}}}}
\def\varinjlim{\mathpalette\varlim@\rightarrowfill@}
\def\varprojlim{\mathpalette\varlim@\leftarrowfill@}
```

Comment: You are introducing spurious spaces with the new lines after `\hbox{` and `\end{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: @campa Thank you! Removing these lines did solve my problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved by comment.